# wsdl2java generating ArrayOf<Type> instead of Type

Tags: java, android, wsdl, wsdl2java

I am using cfx wsdl2java to generate the server (java files). I'm having troubles with one java class. This java class is a complexType and looks like:

EDIT#1: As sugested by @matejko219

```
<xsd:complexType name="TService">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="id"
            type="xsd:int" />
        <xsd:element name="st"
            type="xsd:int" />
        <xsd:element name="loc"
            type="tns:TLoc" />
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="str"
            type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="ti"
            type="xsd:int" />
        <xsd:element name="nump"
            type="xsd:int" />
        <xsd:element name="prc"
            type="xsd:int" />
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="dcrt"
            type="xsd:dateTime" />
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="dini"
            type="xsd:dateTime" />
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="dend"
            type="xsd:dateTime" />
        <xsd:element name="ct"
            type="xsd:int" />
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="ins"
            type="tns:TServiceInspections" />
        <xsd:element name="id"
            type="xsd:int" />
        <xsd:element name="st"
            type="xsd:int" />
        <xsd:element name="loc"
            type="tns:TLoc" />
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="str"
            type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="ti"
            type="xsd:int" />
        <xsd:element name="nump"
            type="xsd:int" />
        <xsd:element name="prc"
            type="xsd:int" />
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="dcrt"
            type="xsd:dateTime" />
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="dini"
            type="xsd:dateTime" />
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="dend"
            type="xsd:dateTime" />
        <xsd:element name="ct"
            type="xsd:int" />
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="ins"
            type="tns:TServiceInspections" />
        <xsd:element name="area"
            type="xsd:int" />
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="desc"
            type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="tsins"
            type="tns:TInspectionServices" />
        <xsd:element name="nc"
            type="xsd:boolean" />
        <xsd:element name="order"
            type="xsd:int" />
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="tasks"
            type="tns:TServiceTasks"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

The generated java file `TService.java` has the variables as ArrayOf 
instead of just the types, for example in `id`.

```
 /**
         * Gets array of all "id" elements
         */
    int[] getIdArray();

    /**
     * Gets ith "id" element
     */
    int getIdArray(int i);

    /**
     * Gets (as xml) array of all "id" elements
     */
    org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlInt[] xgetIdArray();

    /**
     * Gets (as xml) ith "id" element
     */
    org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlInt xgetIdArray(int i);

    /**
     * Returns number of "id" element
     */
    int sizeOfIdArray();

    /**
     * Sets array of all "id" element
     */
    void setIdArray(int[] idArray);

    /**
     * Sets ith "id" element
     */
    void setIdArray(int i, int id);

    /**
     * Sets (as xml) array of all "id" element
     */
    void xsetIdArray(org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlInt[] idArray);

    /**
     * Sets (as xml) ith "id" element
     */
    void xsetIdArray(int i, org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlInt id);

    /**
     * Inserts the value as the ith "id" element
     */
    void insertId(int i, int id);

    /**
     * Appends the value as the last "id" element
     */
    void addId(int id);

    /**
     * Inserts and returns a new empty value (as xml) as the ith "id" element
     */
    org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlInt insertNewId(int i);

    /**
     * Appends and returns a new empty value (as xml) as the last "id" element
     */
    org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlInt addNewId();

    /**
     * Removes the ith "id" element
     */
    void removeId(int i);
```

Is something wrong with my wsdl file?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: I think you don't have to specify maxOccurs attribute. Default value of minOccurs and maxOccurs is 1. Only if you want to make optional element you should set minOccurs to 0.

Comment: I deleted this attributes, just keeping this ones who are set to 0. But still happens the same.. Thank you anyways

Answer (score 0):

Some attributes were repeated, so wsdl2java read it as an array. The correct `wsdl` is:

```
<xsd:complexType name="TService">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="id"
            type="xsd:int" />
        <xsd:element name="st"
            type="xsd:int" />
        <xsd:element name="loc"
            type="tns:TLoc" />
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="str"
            type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="ti"
            type="xsd:int" />
        <xsd:element name="nump"
            type="xsd:int" />
        <xsd:element name="prc"
            type="xsd:int" />
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="dcrt"
            type="xsd:dateTime" />
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="dini"
            type="xsd:dateTime" />
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="dend"
            type="xsd:dateTime" />
        <xsd:element name="ct"
            type="xsd:int" />
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="ins"
            type="tns:TServiceInspections" />
        <xsd:element name="area"
            type="xsd:int" />
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="desc"
            type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="tsins"
            type="tns:TInspectionServices" />
        <xsd:element name="nc"
            type="xsd:boolean" />
        <xsd:element name="order"
            type="xsd:int" />
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="tasks"
            type="tns:TServiceTasks"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```